# Instantiate class based on request parameter

Tags: python, flask

I would like for the user to specify via input parameters which classes they would like to instantiate.  I know how to get the parameter from the request, but how can I instantiate the specified class without using many if statements?

```
request['classToUse'] = Class1
newClass = request['classToUse']()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow the user to specify a string representing one of the available classes.  Look up the class by the string provided.

```
# map class names to classes
avail = dict((cls.__name__, cls) for cls in (Spam, Eggs, Toast))

@app.route('/hello')
def hello():
    name = request.args['name']
    obj = avail[name]()
    return 'you created a {}'.format(name)
```

Navigating to `/hello?name=Toast` will create an instance of the `Toast` class.

Answer (score 0):

if `request` contains `Class1` at `classToUse`, then your code should work. A basic example to show:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 5

d = {'a': A}
my_obj = d['a']()
print my_obj.a
```

returns

> 5

here you can see, that it is instantiated with `()`